# Not Sending password in connection to Postgres - Pandas

Tags: python, excel, postgresql, pandas

I am trying to read in an excel sheet into Pandas and then pass the sheet out to a new not yet created postgresql database.

Constructing my url as per docs here http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/engines.html#postgresql and i am using the [utility helpers](http://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/database_helpers.html) to determine if the database exists or not .

So this is my code (Python 3)

```
import pandas as pd
# import sqlite3
# con = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
import psycopg2
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy_utils import database_exists, create_database


xls = pd.ExcelFile('C:/Users/sayth/Downloads/June_TSO_Coaching/book2.xlsx')
data = xls.parse('ThisOne', index_col=None, na_values=['NA'])


engine = create_engine("postgres://localhost/mydb")
if database_exists(engine.url):
    engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:mypass@localhost/mydb')
    data.to_sql('data',engine)
else:
    create_database(engine.url)
    print("Created" + engine.url)

# data.to_sql('data', con)
pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM data", con)
```

However in a rather long error I notice this section which seems to suggest that the password supplied in create engine is not being used or found.

```
C:\Users\sayth\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py in connect(dsn, database, user, password, host, port, connection_factory, cursor_factory, async, **kwargs)
    162                 for (k, v) in items])
    163 
--> 164     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
    165     if cursor_factory is not None:
    166         conn.cursor_factory = cursor_factory

OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

What is wrong with how I am connecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
engine = create_engine("postgres://localhost/mydb")
```

On that line you need to supply the credentials as well.